# Reproducing a document in LaTeX: A vertical line with branchings

Tags: addlines

I want to create a resume similar to what is seen in the document attached, and I have been trying in vain. [image]

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan,}
    \urlstyle{same}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}
    
    \begin{document}
    \section*{Penn Student}
     210 S 34th StreetPhiladelphia, PA 19104 \href{mailto:email@upenn.edu}{email@upenn.edu} 215-555-5205
    
    Objective:
    
    To further my progress towards completion of the IDP program and licensure through internship with an innovative architectural firm.
    
    2D: Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Illustrator, Adobe InDesign, Adobe Dreamweaver, Adobe Flash
    
    3D: Form-Z, Bentley Systems Microstation, Maya, Rhino, 3D Studio Max and AutoCAD
    
    Drafting, model-making, and rendering
    
    General computing skills with both Microsoft and Macintosh operating systems.
    
    \section*{Extracurriculars:}
     AIASElected First Year Member 20XX - 20XX
    
    Architecture in Education Student teacher at Clara Barton Elementary School Spring 20XX Awards: Honorable Mention 20XX Lifecycle Building Challenge - "Community Revival Shelter" with Greta Modesitt
    
    \section*{Education:}
    University of Pennsylvania School of Design, Philadelphia, PA 9/XX-present Master's of Architecture I Candidate, Received Advanced Placement into the 2nd year, Graduating May 2009
    
    University of Virginia School of Architecture, Charlottesville, VA 8/XX-5/XX Bachelor's of Science in Architecture with a concentration in Design and an Architectural History Minor - Dean's List Six Semesters Cum. GPA 3.597, SAT Verbal 640/Math 670
    
    Governor's School for Global Economics and Technology, Keysville, VA 9/XX-6/XX Took interdisciplinary college-level courses at local community college with students from surrounding counties focusing on communication and interpersonal skills as well as an international awareness in the community.
    
    \section*{Related Professional Experience:}
    Agoos/Lovera Architects, Philadelphia PA, Intern Architect 5/XX-10/XX Made models, prepared construction documents, conducted field measurements, schematic design, and researched material specifications - Haverford Middle School - CD
    
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Case Residence - Measurements, existing conditions drawings, SD, model - Infill Philadelphia Competition - Rendered perspectives
    
      \item Forth Worth Natural History Museum - Model
    
      \item Bianchini Hotel - Measurements, existing conditions drawings, SD
    
    \end{itemize}
    
    Train \& Partners Architects, Charlottesville, VA, Summer Internship 5/XX-8/XX Prepared construction documents, conducted field measurements for measured drawings, and made models.
    
    \begin{itemize}
      \item VCU Rice Center for Environmental Life Sciences - CD
    
      \item Housing Development at Ridge \& Cherry Streets - Site model
    
      \item Charlottesville Fire Houses - Measurements, existing conditions drawings
    
    \end{itemize}
    
    Osteen Phillips Architects, Charlottesville, VA, Summer Internship $\quad$ 6/XX-8/XX Prepared construction documents, conducted material research, conducted field measurements and observations, and observed construction administration.
    
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Newcomb Hall Re-roofing - Measurements, CD
    
      \item Nuclear Reactor Re-roofing - Measurements, CD
    
      \item Campbell Hall Re-roofing - Measurements, CD
    
    \end{itemize}
    
    \section*{Related Academic Experience:}
    TA for ARCH 101: Lessons of the Lawn, Charlottesville, VA 8/XX-12/XX
    
    Attended all lectures and held a weekly discussion section with partner TA where students presented weekly projects and also completed tasks we created to supplement the material taught in lecture. Also graded weekly assignments, consisting of diagrams and essays, as well as midterm and final exams.
        
\end{document}
```

Current result (with all packages but `hyperref` disabled)

[image: result]

Comment: There are a number of ways to achieve this effect, such as a tabular or paracol.  The lines could be added later using `tikz` and `\tikzmark`s.  You could do the whole page using `tikz`.

Comment: @John Kormylo I am still trying to learn many things in LaTeX. Any clues as to how I may start? Thanks

Comment: I would use paracol.  It allows columns of different widths (`\setcolumnwidth`, page 16) and otherwise acts like a normal page (until `\switchcolumn`).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, which pages are you referring to?

Comment: The paracol manual.  Every package has a manual, although MikTeX downloads them separately.

Comment: @Ujan, to find manuals, it's often fastest to enter like `ctan paracol` into your search engine, to find https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol in this case, which holds the manual as .pdf .

Comment: I would suggest to give one of the dedicated CV/resume classes a shot …

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reduce your font size.

Positioning of the tikzpicture is tricky.  It can go anywhere on the page, before of after the `\tikzmark`s, but it has to be on the same page.  And while it is invisible, don't put it at the top of the page.  It acts like `\null` and may add a blank line (or more).  The best place is at the end of something else.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan,}
    \urlstyle{same}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}
    
    \usepackage{paracol}
    \globalcounter*
    \columnseprule=0.4pt
    \setcolumnwidth{0.4\textwidth}% second coul;mn fills the rest of the page
    
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
       
    \begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
    \section*{\hfill\tikzmark{A}Penn Student}
     210 S 34th StreetPhiladelphia, PA 19104 \href{mailto:email@upenn.edu}{email@upenn.edu} 215-555-5205
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \path (current page text area.west) ++ ({0.4\textwidth+0.5\columnsep},0) coordinate (vline);
  \draw (pic cs:A) ++(0,-1pt) coordinate(A) -- (vline |- A);
\end{tikzpicture}

    Objective:
    
    To further my progress towards completion of the IDP program and licensure through internship with an innovative architectural firm.
    
    2D: Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Illustrator, Adobe InDesign, Adobe Dreamweaver, Adobe Flash
    
    3D: Form-Z, Bentley Systems Microstation, Maya, Rhino, 3D Studio Max and AutoCAD
    
    Drafting, model-making, and rendering
    
    General computing skills with both Microsoft and Macintosh operating systems.
    
    \section*{Extracurriculars:}
     AIASElected First Year Member 20XX - 20XX
    
    Architecture in Education Student teacher at Clara Barton Elementary School Spring 20XX Awards: Honorable Mention 20XX Lifecycle Building Challenge - "Community Revival Shelter" with Greta Modesitt
    
    \section*{Education:}
    University of Pennsylvania School of Design, Philadelphia, PA 9/XX-present Master's of Architecture I Candidate, Received Advanced Placement into the 2nd year, Graduating May 2009
    
    University of Virginia School of Architecture, Charlottesville, VA 8/XX-5/XX Bachelor's of Science in Architecture with a concentration in Design and an Architectural History Minor - Dean's List Six Semesters Cum. GPA 3.597, SAT Verbal 640/Math 670
    
    Governor's School for Global Economics and Technology, Keysville, VA 9/XX-6/XX Took interdisciplinary college-level courses at local community college with students from surrounding counties focusing on communication and interpersonal skills as well as an international awareness in the community.
    
\switchcolumn\sloppy
    \section*{Related Professional Experience:}
    Agoos/Lovera Architects, Philadelphia PA, Intern Architect 5/XX-10/XX Made models, prepared construction documents, conducted field measurements, schematic design, and researched material specifications - Haverford Middle School - CD
    
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Case Residence - Measurements, existing conditions drawings, SD, model - Infill Philadelphia Competition - Rendered perspectives
    
      \item Forth Worth Natural History Museum - Model
    
      \item Bianchini Hotel - Measurements, existing conditions drawings, SD
    
    \end{itemize}
    
    Train \& Partners Architects, Charlottesville, VA, Summer Internship 5/XX-8/XX Prepared construction documents, conducted field measurements for measured drawings, and made models.
    
    \begin{itemize}
      \item VCU Rice Center for Environmental Life Sciences - CD
    
      \item Housing Development at Ridge \& Cherry Streets - Site model
    
      \item Charlottesville Fire Houses - Measurements, existing conditions drawings
    
    \end{itemize}
    
    Osteen Phillips Architects, Charlottesville, VA, Summer Internship $\quad$ 6/XX-8/XX Prepared construction documents, conducted material research, conducted field measurements and observations, and observed construction administration.
    
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Newcomb Hall Re-roofing - Measurements, CD
    
      \item Nuclear Reactor Re-roofing - Measurements, CD
    
      \item Campbell Hall Re-roofing - Measurements, CD
    
    \end{itemize}
    
    \section*{Related Academic Experience:}
    TA for ARCH 101: Lessons of the Lawn, Charlottesville, VA 8/XX-12/XX
    
    Attended all lectures and held a weekly discussion section with partner TA where students presented weekly projects and also completed tasks we created to supplement the material taught in lecture. Also graded weekly assignments, consisting of diagrams and essays, as well as midterm and final exams.
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice ... Still some way to go, e.g. reducing text dramatically ...

Comment: @JohnKormylo, great work! Any ideas about how the branches can be added?

Comment: I added one `\tikzmark` to demonstrate how to draw lines.